# On natural examples, how much stronger is this than Löwenheim–Skolem?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

Given a logic (= regular logic in the sense of [Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-2355-7)) $\mathcal{L}$, let a $\downarrow$-sentence be an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ such that, whenever $\mathfrak{M}\models\varphi$ and $\mathfrak{N}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mathfrak{N}\models\varphi$ as well. For instance, the proof of the [Łoś–Tarski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81o%C5%9B%E2%80%93Tarski_preservation_theorem) shows that every $\downarrow$-sentence in a compact extension of $\mathsf{FOL}$ is equivalent to an $\mathsf{FOL}$-sentence of $\forall^*$-form.

Now say that $\mathcal{L}$ is **internally-dLS** iff for each language $\Sigma$ and each $\mathcal{L}[\Sigma]$-sentence $\varphi$ there is a larger language $\Pi$ and an $\mathcal{L}[\Pi]$-sentence $\psi$ such that

- $\psi$ is a $\downarrow$-sentence, and
- for every $\Sigma$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$ we have $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi$ iff $\mathfrak{A}$ has an expansion satisfying $\psi$.

This is a very strong form of the downward (to $\vert\mathcal{L}\vert$) Löwenheim–Skolem property, but it's also what the usual proof of the downward Löwenheim–Skolem theorem for first-order logic actually establishes (the existence of $\psi$ corresponding to Skolemization. I'm curious how common this coincidence is:

> Are there "natural" logics which have the downward Löwenheim–Skolem property but are not internally-dLS?

(Hopefully this isn't too vague!)

One reason I'm interested in this is that the Skolem property leads to an easy proof of a weak form of [Lindström's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem): if $\mathcal{L}$ is an internally-dLS compact logic extending $\mathsf{FOL}$, then we can use the argument of the Los-Tarski theorem to show that the $\mathcal{L}$-elementary classes are all $\mathsf{FOL}$-pseudoelementary, and the result then follows via Craig interpolation (for $\mathsf{FOL}$, not $\mathcal{L}$). Not only does this avoid the characterization of $\equiv_{\mathsf{FOL}}$ via EF-games, it also doesn't use the hypothesis that $\mathcal{L}$ has the relativization property, which is the most difficult aspect of the definition of regular logics.